# Batch file get's a random "1" added before the output command.

Tags: windows, batch-file

Ok so I have a batch file that shows up differently in CMD than how I wrote it.

Original Line - and ADB command to start a shell as root, and print to a file what I would normally see in the window.

```
adb shell "su" >rootcheck.tk
```

When I run the batch file this is what shows up in the window...

```
adb shell "su" 1>rootcheck.tk
```

Now oddly enough it still prints the file that I need it to, and correctly. my biggest issue is that the batch file doesn't close automatically. I tried to add an exit command but it doesn't run any commands after the first one that shows up with that random "1" before the output.

I'm sure it's something small and stupid that I'm missing here. Thanks!

Comment: The `1` refers to the stdout stream, `1>` is redirecting stdout to something. 2 is stderr, the same as in many unix shells. If you do `dir > a.txt 2>&1` you would redirect both stdout and stderr to the file.

Comment: Nothing is wrong. `>` is shorthand for `1>`

Comment: what causes it to pause and not close? I tried using the call command like "foxidrive" said below, but that doesn't work any better. if one freezes the rest of the calls just don't execute.

Comment: Is there any way to remove the "1" so that the command can run?

Comment: The one isn't even in the batch file, it's produces when the batch file is run. I figured it out though, it was how the batch file was being launched. I was able to trick the software by having it lauch a VB script that launches the batch file, and it fixed it. weird I know but it works :)

Answer (score 1):

The `adb shell` command is keeping the window open UIAM.
Using this will launch the adb in another window.

```
start "" adb shell "su" >rootcheck.tk
```

When using other batch files in a script the you need to use this syntax

```
call mybatch.bat
```

otherwise the script will not continue.

Comment: No batch files were being called in the script.

Comment: I was able to fix it by calling it from a Visual Basic script instead, something about how it runs it is better... weird...

Comment: @Ajster1989 is there a chance you can share the VB script you used? thanks

Comment: shell.run="[yourpath][batch.bat]" I just used that to call the batch file I needed to output the text, something about ADB was acting funny.